# Chrome Plugin: Accessing named pipes on Windows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to write a plugin for Chrome which, if running on Windows and the browser's URL matches something specific, can open a named pipe to a certain process running on the OS.

What's the best choice of plugin for Chrome? Should I go with a Native Client or can I use something less intrusive (although I realize named pipes by definition are quite intrusive)?

Comment: My understanding of Native Client is it's sandboxed; I seriously doubt you can do this with NaCl. AFAIK the only other option is NSAPI.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was expecting, too. I might just look into using an NSAPI wrapper then. Cheers!

Comment: Did you mean NPAPI? If so, yes, you can use NPAPI plugin for that purpose... You might also want to look at Firebreath if you are developing NPAPI plugin...

Answer (score 4):

Native Client is indeed sandboxed, as indicated by the comments, and NPAPI is retired.

Two current solutions for contacting a running native app are those:

1. Use HTTP, optionally with WebSockets, with the native application (or a proxy application that will talk to a third-party app using any native method, including pipes) acting as a server on `localhost` and the extension trying to connect to a known port. [GhostText](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText) is an example of this architecture.
2. Use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). It's important to understand limitations of this approach:

   - It acts as a pipe to an external process, but must follow the Native Messaging (JSON-based) protocol.
   - It cannot attach to a currently running process (or pipe): Chrome can only start a new instance of the Native Host, and contact cannot be initiated from outside.

   So with those limitations in mind, your Native Host would be a proxy that will, itself, attach to the named pipe in question and relay the data, translating it to/from the Native Messaging protocol.

Comment: How can native messaging be used with named pipes?  Do I need an external process that takes JSON data and then connects to named pipes?  Or, is there a way to do STDIO with pipes with Native Messaging directly?  For context, I need to send two independent streams to one FFmpeg process simultaneously for them to be merged, which requires more than what I can do with STDIO.  A named pipe is necessary.

Comment: Your understanding that you'll need a "proxy" process that'll connect to named pipes is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You know, strangely enough I just noticed you can view named pipes via:

file://./pipe/

I discovered this when I was reading the Wikipedia article about them, copied it, and then later thought I copied a URL and accidentally pasted that into chrome instead.

You can't even access that from explorer or the file system.